# Javascript to stop HTML 5 video upon close

Tags: javascript, html, video, adobe-edge

I am a total newbie to coding, and am working on a project in Adobe Edge Animate. I have created a return button that enables the user to click on it while the video is playing, thus closing out of the video and returning them to the main menu. This works, however, the video audio continues to play in the background.

Does anyone know how I can get the video to pause playing at the same time as it returns to the main menu?

Here's my code

```
(function ($, Edge, compId) {
    var Composition = Edge.Composition,
        Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for commonly used Edge classes

    //Edge symbol: 'stage'
    (function (symbolName) {
        Symbol.bindTriggerAction(compId, symbolName, "Default Timeline", 1000, function (sym, e) {
            // sym.$("name") resolves an Edge Animate element name to a DOM
            // element that can be used with jQuery
            var vid = sym.$("Rectangle");

            vid.html('<video width="1920" height = "1080" src = "video/OurChangingWorld_AirQuality_Final_v2.mp4" type ="video/mp4" controls autoplay></video>');
        });
        //Edge binding end

        Symbol.bindTriggerAction(compId, symbolName, "Default Timeline", 0, function (sym, e) {
            sym.stop();
        });
        //Edge binding end

        Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_Button_AirQuality}", "click", function (sym, e) {
            sym.play("Video 1");
        });
        //Edge binding end

        Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_Return_button-01}", "click", function (sym, e) {
            sym.play("Main");
        });
        //Edge binding end
    })("stage");
    //Edge symbol end:'stage'
})(jQuery, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-3854874");
```

Comment: What browser are you getting this behavior in?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are just hiding the video instance. So it keeps playing.
To get control over the video instance you can simply add an id attribute to the video tag like this:

```
vid.html('<video id="myvideo" width="1920" height = "1080" ...
```

After that you can use a standard jQuery selector to get a reference to the previously created video instance to control it (play/stop/pause/remove it):

```
$("#myvideo").pause();
```

Here you will find a useful description of the HTML5 video/audio API:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Hope that helps. Happy Animating,

Simon

Comment: first , welcome, http://www.w3fools.com/ , second USE MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: wow. I didn't know that you get a slap in the face when you link to w3schools. I personally cannot report anything bad about that resource. Quite the opposite, they saved my life when switching from Flash/Flex back to web standards and especially when I was building a HTML5 interactive video player.